# Routing a request to a particular uwsgi worker

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I'm running a python flask application on uswgi with 4 workers.

The application has a cache that needs to be periodically refreshed and warmed up. I'd like to do this with an external job that hits a url but I need to ensure the cache is warmed up on all 4 workers.

Is there a way to route a request to a particular worker? Ideally I'd just like to have a special header or query parameter that does this.

Comment: You can use uwsgi with nginx and its location feature to redirect requests to different upstreams listening in different sockets http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html

Comment: Thanks @rendrum however I am running a single uwsgi instance exposing all workers on the same socket. I could switch to multiple uswgi processes but then I would lose the worker management abilities uwsgi gives me.

Answer (score 0):

Worker load balancing is handled by the kernel and there's no way to force requests to hit a specific worker.

You'll have to either move your cache to somewhere all workers can access (redis, mongo, sql db, etc) or have a process/thread running on your workers to refresh the cache (Celery, etc)